# R ggpubr: move legend title above the legend keys

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am struggling with the legend position within ggpubr. I know that I can modify the legend position p.e. by `ggpar(legend = "bottom")`. But, ***how to place legend title above the legend keys?***

In `ggplot2`, it seems that `guide_legend(title.position = "top")` should do this, but how to make it work with `ggpubr`? (thanks to @c06n and link here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html). I would like to combine the `ggplot2` and `ggpubr` but I don't know exactly why.

[image]

Dummy example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))

# Plot "len" by "dose" and
# Change line types and point shapes by a second groups: "supp"
p<- ggline(df2, "dose", "len",
       linetype = "supp", shape = "supp",
       color = "supp", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))

# Seems not working
ggpar(p,
  linetype = guide_legend(title = "My title", title.position = "top"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot legend: position of key relative to labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728302/ggplot-legend-position-of-key-relative-to-labels)

Comment: It could be. But for me is a little different. There's a trick, because `guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))` works but not `guides(shape = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know `ggpubr`, it seems like a wrapper for `ggplot2`. If that is true, and/or it has implemented the same functionality as `ggplot2`, you should be able to achieve that via `legend guide`, see [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html). I think it is `title.position` you need to adjust.

If you cannot achieve that with `ggpubr`, I suggest using `ggplot2` instead, perhaps adjusting the theme to your needs.

Edit. @markus has the answer, so to put it all in one place:

```
p <- ggline(df2, "dose", "len",
           linetype = "supp", 
           shape = "supp",
           color = "supp", 
           palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "top", 
                              title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Interesting question though from @Bruno Pinheiro as to why only `color` (and `fill`) will work, but not `shape` or `linetype`. This would be relevant if the plot needs to be monochrome. All three should work equally well as grouping factors.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: thank you @c06n but your approach does not work. I have updated my question and I am starting to remake things in ggplot2

Comment: Your suggestion is correct @c06n, the code is `p + guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))`

Comment: Awesome @markus, thank you, your suggestion works! Please, can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @maycca Glad it worked. I think @c06n should include the code in his answer which pointed into the right direction. BTW It works because `ggpubr` returns a `ggplot` object that you can modify in the usual way.

Comment: Sorry guys. I started to make some tests here and while this new comments were made, which I saw after post an answer. I will keep it till @c06n edit his answer and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

These options are working here.

With `ggpubr`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))

library(ggpubr)
p <- ggline(df2, "dose", "len",
       linetype = "supp", shape = "supp",
       color = "supp", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))

p + guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

I don't know why, but if i set the guide for another aesthetic the legend title position do not change:

```
p + guides(shape = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
p + guides(linetype = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

It's a good question to be made for `ggplot2` experts.

And here is the same working in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = dose, y = len, colour = supp)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = supp, linetype = supp)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = supp)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```